# Using webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById to click folder by it's name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, click, getelementbyid

i am trying to click on a folder inside website after i logged in to the website.
i need to use a method in c#

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("s23").InvokeMember("click");
```

the folder name (Managment), when i get it's source it like that

```
<div class="dTreeNode">
   <a href="javascript: a.o(20);">
      <img id="ja20" src="dtree/img/plusbottom.gif" alt="">
   </a>
   <img id="ia20" src="dtree/img/folder.gif" alt="">
   <a id="sa20" class="node" href="javascript:a.oo(900);" onmouseover="window.status='Management';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;" onclick="javascript: a.s(20);">
      Management
   </a>
</div>
```

i need to click that folder programmatic using c#
thanks

Comment: What is this `s23` you're trying to click? There's no such ID in your *sample* (possibly, provide an URL to test). What is the element you actually want to *click*? Do you have IFrames in that HTML? + Could you format your code/html?

Comment: it's sub item inside the folder, i need to click the folder then the sub item (as20 then as23)

Comment: Sorry i mean folder id (id="sa20"), then sub item (id="sa23")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the `<a> element`, here is a workaround that may help you.

Get the element by `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName` method, then use `foreach` to traverse elements.

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement html in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
{
    if (html.InnerText == "Management")
    {
        html.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your respond , but it not success with me,, i tried this function on other site and it works fine but on my site not success